# Tikz: Large block in matrix and separate arrows (block diagram)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I an trying to write the following block diagram in tikz.
[image: What I want to do]
Because it mainly consists in aligned blocks, I am using a matrix for the layout. I wrote the following tikz instructions, which give the picture at the end of this post.
Here are the problems I have:

- I don't know how to do the large blocks with 2 inputs / 2 outputs
- I don't know how to deal with the arrows so that they do not superpose each other on the C blocks

My document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\tikzstyle{B} = [draw,align=center]

\tikzset{
  max width/.style args={#1}{
    execute at begin node={\begin{varwidth}{#1}},
      execute at end node={\end{varwidth}}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[column sep=5pt,row sep=10pt] {
        \coordinate (tmp_HH1_1);   &
        &
        &
        &
        \coordinate (tmp_x1);  &
        &
        &
        &
        &
        &
        \\
        &
        &
        &
        \coordinate (tmp_P1);  &
        &
        &
        &
        &

        &
        \\
        &
        \coordinate (u1); \node[above][max width=3cm] {$u_1$}; &
        \node[B]    (C1) {$C_1$}; &
        \node[B]    (P1) {$P_1$}; &
        \coordinate (x1);  &
        \node[B]    (H1) {$H_1$}; &
        \node[B]    (D1) {$D_1$}; &
        \node[B]    (R1) {$R_1$}; &
        \coordinate (yy1); &
        &
        \coordinate (y1); \node[above][max width=3cm] {$y_1$};
        \\
        &
        \coordinate (u2); \node[above][max width=3cm] {$u_2$}; &
        \node[B]    (C2) {$C_2$}; &
        \node[B]    (P2) {$P_2$}; &
        \coordinate (x2);  &
        \node[B]    (H2) {$H_2$}; &
        \node[B]    (D2) {$D_2$}; &
        \node[B]    (R2) {$R_2$}; &
        &
        \coordinate (yy2);&
         \coordinate (y2); \node[above][max width=3cm] {$y_2$};
        \\
        \coordinate (tmp_HH1_2);    &
        &
        &
        \coordinate (tmp_P2);  &
        &
        &
        &
        &
        \\
        &
        &
        &
        &
        \coordinate (tmp_x2);  &
        &
        &
        &
        \\
        &
        &
        &
        &
        &
        \node[B]    (HH1) {$H^{-1}_1$}; &
        &

        \\
        &
        &
        &
        &
        &
        \node[B]    (HH2) {$H^{-1}_2$}; &
        &
        \\

        &
        &
        &
        &
       \coordinate (delta); \node[below][max width=3cm] {$\delta$};  &
        &
        &
        \\
    };

    \draw[->] (u1) -- (C1);
    \draw[->] (C1) -- (P1);
    \draw[->] (P1) -- (H1);
    \draw[->] (H1) -- (D1);
    \draw[->] (D1) -- (R1);
    \draw[->] (R1) -- (y1);

    \draw[-] (x1) -- (tmp_x1);
    \draw[->] (tmp_x1) -| (C1);
    \draw[-] (P1) -- (tmp_P1);
    \draw[->] (tmp_P1) -| (C1);

    \draw[->] (u2) -- (C2);
    \draw[->] (C2) -- (P2);
    \draw[->] (P2) -- (H2);
    \draw[->] (H2) -- (D2);
    \draw[->] (D2) -- (R2);
    \draw[->] (R2) -- (y2);

    \draw[-] (x2) -- (tmp_x2);
    \draw[->] (tmp_x2) -| (C2);
    \draw[-] (P2) -- (tmp_P2);
    \draw[->] (tmp_P2) -| (C2);

    \draw[->] (yy1) |- (HH1);
    \draw[->] (yy2) |- (HH2);

    \draw[->] (HH2) -| (delta);

    \draw[-] (HH1) -| (tmp_HH1_1);
    \draw[->] (tmp_HH1_1) -| (C1);
    \draw[->] (tmp_HH1_2) -| (C2);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image: What I have]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the big blocks, one approach is to modify the nodes you currently have to be on the form

```
\node[B, draw=none] (H1) {\phantom{$H_1$}};
```

So added `draw=none` and placed the node contents in a `\phantom`, meaning that you essentially get an invisible node. (There are other ways of achieving the same.) To draw the big node you can, after the `matrix`, do

```
\node [inner sep=-0.5\pgflinewidth,fit=(H1)(H2), draw] {$H$};
```

To fix the overlapping arrows, you can shift the endpoints a bit, by making the final coordinates of the form

```
([xshift=3pt]C1.north)
```

instead of just `C1`.

Complete code below. Note I also drew the arrows going into the C blocks in one path, as this will improve the look of the corners. (Try zooming really far in on, for example, the `tmp_X2` corner.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\tikzset{
  B/.style={draw,align=center},
  max width/.style args={#1}{
    execute at begin node={\begin{varwidth}{#1}},
      execute at end node={\end{varwidth}}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[column sep=5pt,row sep=10pt] {
        \coordinate (tmp_HH1_1);   &
        &
        &
        &
        \coordinate (tmp_x1);  &
        &
        &
        &
        &
        &
        \\
        &
        &
        &
        \coordinate (tmp_P1);  &
        &
        &
        &
        &

        &
        \\
        &
        \coordinate (u1); \node[above][max width=3cm] {$u_1$}; &
        \node[B]    (C1) {$C_1$}; &
        \node[B]    (P1) {$P_1$}; &
        \coordinate (x1);  &
        \node[B, draw=none]    (H1) {\phantom{$H_1$}}; &
        \node[B]    (D1) {$D_1$}; &
        \node[B, draw=none]    (R1) {\phantom{$R_1$}}; &
        \coordinate (yy1); &
        &
        \coordinate (y1); \node[above][max width=3cm] {$y_1$};
        \\
        &
        \coordinate (u2); \node[above][max width=3cm] {$u_2$}; &
        \node[B]    (C2) {$C_2$}; &
        \node[B]    (P2) {$P_2$}; &
        \coordinate (x2);  &
        \node[B, draw=none]    (H2) {\phantom{$H_2$}}; &
        \node[B]    (D2) {$D_2$}; &
        \node[B, draw=none]    (R2) {\phantom{$R_2$}}; &
        &
        \coordinate (yy2);&
         \coordinate (y2); \node[above][max width=3cm] {$y_2$};
        \\
        \coordinate (tmp_HH1_2);    &
        &
        &
        \coordinate (tmp_P2);  &
        &
        &
        &
        &
        \\
        &
        &
        &
        &
        \coordinate (tmp_x2);  &
        &
        &
        &
        \\
        &
        &
        &
        &
        &
        \node[B]    (HH1) {$H^{-1}_1$}; &
        &

        \\
        &
        &
        &
        &
        &
        \node[B]    (HH2) {$H^{-1}_2$}; &
        &
        \\

        &
        &
        &
        &
       \coordinate (delta); \node[below][max width=3cm] {$\delta$};  &
        &
        &
        \\
    };

    \node [inner sep=-0.5\pgflinewidth,fit=(H1)(H2), draw] {$H$};
    \node [inner sep=-0.5\pgflinewidth,fit=(R1)(R2), draw] {$R$};

    \draw[->] (u1) -- (C1);
    \draw[->] (C1) -- (P1);
    \draw[->] (P1) -- (H1);
    \draw[->] (H1) -- (D1);
    \draw[->] (D1) -- (R1);
    \draw[->] (R1) -- (y1);

    \draw[->] (x1) -- (tmp_x1) -| (C1);
    \draw[->] (P1) -- (tmp_P1) (tmp_P1) -| ([xshift=3pt]C1.north);

    \draw[->] (u2) -- (C2);
    \draw[->] (C2) -- (P2);
    \draw[->] (P2) -- (H2);
    \draw[->] (H2) -- (D2);
    \draw[->] (D2) -- (R2);
    \draw[->] (R2) -- (y2);

    \draw[->] (x2) -- (tmp_x2) -| (C2);
    \draw[->] (P2) -- (tmp_P2) -| ([xshift=3pt]C2.south);

    \draw[->] (yy1) |- (HH1);
    \draw[->] (yy2) |- (HH2);

    \draw[->] (HH2) -| (delta);

    \draw[->] (HH1) -| (tmp_HH1_1) -| ([xshift=-3pt]C1.north);
    \draw[->] (tmp_HH1_2) -| ([xshift=-3pt]C2.south);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know about draw=none and  \phantom so my backup plan was to put 4 temporary coordinates and draw lines to form a rectangle.
Thank you showing that draw lines can be chained. I always did those in several steps because \draw[->] (pt1) -|- (pt2); didn't work.